# Trajectory Design Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I've been tasked with creating a small demonstration for educational purposes of the [Morris Screening Method](https://gsa-module.readthedocs.io/en/stable/implementation/morris_screening_method.html) but am having trouble implementing the trajectory design matrix in Mathematica. It's a small example of 6 levels in 2 variables. The matrix should return a series of $k+1$ perturbed ${x_1, x_2}$ to use in the function of interest.

[image]
[image]

I feel like I'm close at the moment but after struggling yesterday I feel like I should now raise my hand and ask for Matrix help. I'm having trouble interpreting 1. $x^*$ the matrix of random start points and 2. what the factorial increment diagonal matrix is. I can't seem to get the dimensions right so it threads over the equation smoothly.

```
ClearAll[RandDstar, TrajectoryMatrix]

RandDstar := RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]

TrajectoryMatrix[grid_] := 
 Module[{r, b, x, JK, d, p, diff, \[CapitalDelta]},
  b = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {k + 1, k}]];
  x = ConstantArray[RandomChoice[grid], k + 1];
  d = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[RandDstar, {k + 1, k}]];
  p = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
  JK = ConstantArray[1, {k + 1, k}];
  diff = First[Differences[grid[[;; 2, 2]]]];
  \[CapitalDelta] = DiagonalMatrix[Table[diff, k + 1]];
  (* Apply equation to matrixes to return b* *)
  (x + (\[CapitalDelta]/2 * (((2*b) - JK)*d) + JK))*p
  ]

Block[{gridWorld, k = 2},
 (*6 level Grid World with 2 variables *)
 gridWorld = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1, 0.2}, {y, 0, 1, 0.2}], 1];
 TrajectoryMatrix[gridWorld]
 ]
```

Comment: At first glance, I think the problem lies in your multiplication of matrices. Instead of ``*``, you should use the matrix multiplication ``.``. This produces a result (not sure if it's correct, though) without errors: ``(x + ((\[CapitalDelta]/2) . (((2*b) - JK)*d) + JK)) . p``